# Cleanly shutting down Spring Persistence HSQL In Memory Database

Tags: java, spring, jpa, orm, hsqldb

I have an In-Memory database for running some Unit tests. I use Spring ORM 3.2.1 to start this In-Memory database. The spring context is part of a Web application accessible via some REST interface implemented using Jersey 1.10. My tests are implemented as a JerseyTest and thus the spring application context is hidden from the actual rest runner. My problem now is cleanly shutting down the database between tests, so that one test does not see data saved by the previous test.

My old implementation using only JPA and HSQL called:

```
if (factory != null && factory.isOpen()) {
        EntityManager manager = factory.createEntityManager();
        manager.getTransaction().begin();
        manager.createNativeQuery("SHUTDOWN").executeUpdate();
        manager.getTransaction().commit();
}
```

on the database to make sure everything is removed.

If I do the same on my Spring created database I get an error:

```
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: connection exception:  closed
Error Code: -1353
Call: SHUTDOWN
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="SHUTDOWN")
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:308)
at de.tudresden.inf.rn.intellix.tudix.HsqldbShutdownListener.contextDestroyed(HsqldbShutdownListener.java:45)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletContextImpl.destroyListeners(ServletContextImpl.java:186)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.servlet.ServletHandler.destroy(ServletHandler.java:768)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpHandlerChain.destroy(HttpHandlerChain.java:317)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer.tearDownHttpHandler(HttpServer.java:303)
at org.glassfish.grizzly.http.server.HttpServer.stop(HttpServer.java:366)
at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.spi.container.grizzly2.web.GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory$GrizzlyWebTestContainer.stop(GrizzlyWebTestContainerFactory.java:154)
at com.sun.jersey.test.framework.JerseyTest.tearDown(JerseyTest.java:316)
at de.tudresden.inf.rn.intellix.tudix.TudixInterfaceTest.tearDown(TudixInterfaceTest.java:127)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:33)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:271)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:70)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:50)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:238)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:63)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:236)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:53)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:229)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:309)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-4002] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.1.v20130918-f2b9fc5): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException
Internal Exception: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: connection exception: closed
Error Code: -1353
Call: SHUTDOWN
Query: DataModifyQuery(sql="SHUTDOWN")
at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.DatabaseException.sqlException(DatabaseException.java:340)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.processExceptionForCommError(DatabaseAccessor.java:1611)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:674)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.executeCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:558)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.basicExecuteCall(AbstractSession.java:1991)
at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.server.ClientSession.executeCall(ClientSession.java:298)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:242)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:228)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelectCall(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:271)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.queries.DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.executeNoSelect(DatasourceCallQueryMechanism.java:251)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DataModifyQuery.executeDatabaseQuery(DataModifyQuery.java:85)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.execute(DatabaseQuery.java:899)
at org.eclipse.persistence.queries.DatabaseQuery.executeInUnitOfWork(DatabaseQuery.java:798)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.UnitOfWorkImpl.internalExecuteQuery(UnitOfWorkImpl.java:2896)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1793)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1775)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.AbstractSession.executeQuery(AbstractSession.java:1740)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.QueryImpl.executeUpdate(QueryImpl.java:298)
... 32 more
Caused by: java.sql.SQLNonTransientConnectionException: connection exception: closed
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCUtil.sqlException(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCPreparedStatement.<init>(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.jdbc.JDBCConnection.prepareStatement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.DelegatingConnection.prepareStatement(DelegatingConnection.java:281)
at org.apache.commons.dbcp.PoolingDataSource$PoolGuardConnectionWrapper.prepareStatement(PoolingDataSource.java:313)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1556)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.prepareStatement(DatabaseAccessor.java:1505)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseCall.prepareStatement(DatabaseCall.java:778)
at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.databaseaccess.DatabaseAccessor.basicExecuteCall(DatabaseAccessor.java:619)
... 47 more
Caused by: org.hsqldb.HsqlException: connection exception: closed
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.error.Error.error(Unknown Source)
at org.hsqldb.Session.execute(Unknown Source)
... 55 more
```

It seems the database has already been closed. But it has definitely not, since I can see the data from the previous test in the next one.

The database is defined as a spring bean in application-context.xml like so:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource"
    destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver">
    </property>
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:hsqldb:mem:db;sql.enforce_size=false;sql.enforce_strict_size=false"></property>
    <property name="username" value="sa"></property>
    <property name="password" value=""></property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory" />
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
    <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="PU" />
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean
            class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.EclipseLinkJpaVendorAdapter">
            <property name="showSql" value="false" />
            <property name="generateDdl" value="false" />
        </bean>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaPropertyMap">
        <map>
            <entry key="eclipselink.weaving" value="false" />
            <entry key="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="create-tables" />
            <entry key="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" />
            <entry key="eclipselink.logging.level.sql" value="SEVERE" />
            <entry key="eclipselink.logging.parameters" value="false" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here is a minimal example of one test case:

```
public final class TudixInterfaceTest extends JerseyTest {

@Override
protected AppDescriptor configure() {
    Map<String, String> initParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    initParams.put("com.sun.jersey.config.property.packages", "my.resource.package");

    Builder builder = new WebAppDescriptor.Builder(initParams);
    return builder.initParam("application-context", "application-context.xml").contextPath("/").build();
}


@Test
public void test() {
    // Access REST interface, saving some stuff to the in memory database on server side.
    // Assert the result on client side.
}
```

Has someone a clue on how to properly shut down an HSQL In-Memory database in such a scenario?

Comment: Is your in-memory (HSQLDB?) database defined as a bean in the spring application context? If so, you can tell Spring to re-initialise the context between tests - which will clear out the database.

Comment: Hi. I added the definition of the In-Memory database to my question. The @DirtiesContext annotation however does not work, since I am running a JerseyTest which starts up a Grizzly Server and runs the tests against a REST interface. This means the spring context is hidden from the actual test runner.

Comment: Are you able to get a handle on the `applicationContext` from within the test (possibly through `WebApplicationContextUtils.getApplicationContext()`? If so, you could put a call to `applicationContext.refresh()` inside the `tearDown()` method

Comment: I have a ServletFilter registered on server shutdown. I can get a handle to the Spring application context there. But the application context (class: org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext) has no refresh() method.

Comment: You need to cast it to a `ConfigurableApplicationContext` before you can call `refresh()`. However, it really needs to be called between each test run - in the tearDown method. It doesn't sound as though you can easily get a handle on it from within your test.

Comment: Nope. I cannot get a handle to it from within my test. Refreshing on Server shutdown is not enough. But I do not understand why? The server gets shutdown after each test. I verified that fact.